# Empty Accessor Method for Property

Tags: ios

I'm new to iOS and trying to understand some Objective C code which I need to translate to Java.

In the .h file there are a lot of method declarations like this:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject<NSCoding>
    // Some score
    - (int)score;
@end
```

and in the .m file there is:

```
@interface SomeClass()

@property(nonatomic) int score;

@end
```

but the accessor method score that is declared in SomeClass is never implemented anywhere.

So my questions are:

1. Is it usual to put the properties in the .m file, even though it is written inside @interface (which for me belongs to the .h file)
2. Why is there an unimplemented accessor method (or is it something else?). @property automatically creates accessor methods, so this seems to be useless. Is it just so that one can comment the method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a note, the code you attached is bad practice in my opinion since they should have a readonly property in the header and then just redeclare it as *not* readonly in the class extension.

That aside:

> 1. Is it usual to put the properties in the .m file, even though it is written inside @interface (which for me belongs to the .h file)?

If you have a readonly property in the header and you want to add a setter method in your implementation file, for internal use, then you can just redeclare the property in a class extension and the setter will be created for you. Therefore, you don't have to write the setter yourself.

In your case, the programmer had a property with a getter and a setter but only wanted to publicly expose the getter method.

> 2. Why is there an unimplemented accessor method (or is it something else?). @property automatically creates accessor methods, so this seems to be useless. Is it just so that one can comment the method?

The accessor method isn't actually unimplemented, it's just automatically created. The @property declaration, with the latest version of LLVM, with go through a process called autosynthesis. This autosynthesis will look at the @property declaration and generate corresponding setter and accessor methods for it.

The programmer just wanted to publicly expose the getter method, that's why they put it in the public class interface.

Here's an example of autogenerated getters and setters:

```
@interface MyClass ()

@property (nonatomic) int integerOne;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) int integerTwo;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, getter = myIntegerThree) int integerThree;

@end
```

What these will do is as follows:

**integerOne**: generate an instance variable named `_integerOne`, create a getter method named `integerOne` and create a setter method named `setIntegerOne:`

**integerTwo**: generate an instance variable named `_integerTwo`, create a getter method named `integerTwo`

**integerThree**: generate an instance variable named `_integerThree`, create a getter method named `myIntegerThree`

You can avoid autosynthesis by just implementing the autogenerated methods. If you implement all of the autogenerated methods, you will also have to synthesize the instance variable yourself too, though. For example, if I declare a readonly property and then override the automatically created getter, I will have to put `@synthesize property=_property;` at the top of my implementation file so I can get an instance variable named `_property`.